# Virtualization in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization

I have an existing Centos 5 installation.  I would like to upgrade to Ubuntu.  Thing is, I don't want to be down for as long as it will take to get my entire environment moved over - software installed, connectivity configured, etc.  I'd like to take it one step at a time.

But I don't really want to keep rebooting back and forth from the new OS to the old OS.  That's what I did last time I upgraded to a new OS, and it got old real fast.

So, since my new MB is virtualization-ready (AMD Phenom II 945 quad-core), I figured I could create a virtual machine, under the new OS installation, that ran the old OS installation.

The problem is that the documentation I've been able to find has been pretty sparse.  I've found a lot of possibilities, and little info on which would be capable of doing what I want.

I have a new Ubuntu 9.10 installation, and a second disk containing the Centos 5 installation.  And I don't know where to go next.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should this be on ServerFault.com?

Comment: are you sure about that ubuntu version number? It doesn't look right

Comment: Sorry, Ubunto 9.10

Comment: This is content for superuser.com

Comment: @Mark This is a good question. If your avatar wasn't a bulldog I would definitely have something to add.

Comment: (1) +1 on move-to-serverfault. (2) Ubuntu includes the libvirt/kvm virtualization stack, which will take advantage of your CPU's support. If your chassis permits, you might just plug the old drives into your new machine and pass them straight through to your VMs.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq Huh? Also, that's a pug dog.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a virtual environment is possible, but may not be what you need.  If you really want it, look into VMware's converter to read the Centos disk and create a VM, then use VMPlayer to run that VM under Ubuntu.  I've found these tools to be pretty easy to use.

VMware converter will read the disk and create a new disk image file - this means you need to have a place big enough to put this disk image.  However, I believe it is also possible to create a VM that uses the physical disk image, I just haven't used VMPlayer this way myself.

Since you say you have these on separate disks, I'm assuming you mean you have two harddrives, one with Ubuntu and one with Centos.  Why not just make sure both disks are plugged in and running?

With Ubuntu running as the boot disk, create a mount point `mkdir /centos`, mount the disk there with something like `mount /dev/sdb1 /centos` and look for any info you need on the Centos disk.  To make that permanent, add a line to /etc/fstab something like

> /dev/sdb1         /centos         ext3   defaults   1 2

Most of the system info you want will be under /centos/etc, and you should be able to use your existing Centos disk /centos/home/ as your login directory, so you don't even need to copy your home directory to the new disk.

Answer (score 0):

KVM is really good for non-graphical VM's.  VMWare is a pain these days in Linux IMHO.  I've switched to [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and have been happy running various VM's (including Windows 7) on Ubuntu AMD64 9.10 and 9.04 installs.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel confident, you can try ***VirtualBox*** with [**raw disk support**](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk). This should leave your system on a separate partition/drive intact.  However, I'm not sure how your system would react to switching back and forth between virtualized and normal boot. Windows could probably freak out here. ;-)